# Code Sign error: The identity 'iPhone Developer: x Xxxxx' doesn't match any identity in any profile

Tags: iphone, iphone-sdk-3.0, certificate, code-signing

I get this build error when I build my iPhone project to run on my device:

```
 **Code Sign error: The identity 'iPhone Developer: x Xxxxx' doesn't match any identity in any profile**
```

My development code signing certificate expired so I got a new one. On my first attempt I created a new CSR and got the message above. The second time I reused my original CSR and got the same result. Another strange thing is the new certificate has an extra string with brackets after my name in the "common name" when I look at it using Keychain Access like this:

```
iPhone Developer: x Xxxxx **(3BDUAJYC9Q)**
```

`My original certificate didn't have that.

```
I have Xcode Version 3.1.3
Component versions
Xcode IDE: 1191.0
Xcode Core: 1192.0
ToolSupport: 1186.0
```

Does anyone know how to solve this?

Comment: My Answer : http://stackoverflow.com/a/12294275/1603072

Answer (score 19, accepted):

I think you need to create new provisioning profiles based on your new certificate.

Log on to developer.apple.com and go to the iOS Provisioning Portal -> Provisioning -> Development. Most likely, the profile you once created has expired, so just renew and redownload it.

Answer (score 44):

1. Right Click the Project (eg. x.xcodeproject) and select Show Package Content
2. Open project.pbxproj with TextEdit
3. Search for all "CODE_SIGN_IDENTITY[sdk=iphoneos*]" and set it to  "CODE_SIGN_IDENTITY[sdk=iphonesos*]" = "iPhone Developer";
4. Search for "PROVISIONING_PROFILE[sdk=iphoneos*]" and set it to 
   "PROVISIONING_PROFILE[sdk=iphoneos*]" = "";
5. Save the file
6. Reopen the Xcode project or select "Read from Disk" resulting from Xcode the prompt.
7. This Worked for me. I hope it works for you too.

Comment: Great, that led me to the solution of my problem, see here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1072311/code-sign-error-the-identity-iphone-developer-x-xxxxx-doesnt-match-any-ident/6376483#6376483. Thanks!

Comment: Argh.  Mine need those modifications, but TextEdit won't let me save them.  File is not locked and I have read/write on it, however it's saying I don't have permission.  What's the magic trick to get it to let me save?

Comment: PROVISIONING_PROFILE does not exist in project.pbxproj in my version of Xcode. Using Xcode 4.6.3 (4H1503).

Answer (score 3):

Following kw4m3n4's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1072311/code-sign-error-the-identity-iphone-developer-x-xxxxx-doesnt-match-any-ident/3097199#3097199), I found the special characters (umlaute) in my name where messed up in the file. I fixed it like this:

1. right click the .xproject file (e.g. yourproject.xproject) and select Show Package Content
2. open project.pbxproj with textEdit
3. search and replace the messed up name / umlauts (e.g. "Tim B√ºthe" -> "Tim Büthe")

Answer (score 1):

If you have multiple developer accounts, then make sure you're signed into the right one in xCode- that was the problem when I had this error.

Answer (score 1):

For me the problem was that I did choose debug on device by accident, as I inteded to switch to iPhone simulator. To debug on an emulator it worked as before by selecting simulator in the menu.

Answer (score 0):

Silly me... The problem was I still needed to create a new "Provisioning Profile" which uses the new certificate in the iPhone program portal and load it into Xcode. I didn't need to add the extra string after my name in the code signing section for debug.