# Xcode iPhone project Code Signing error

Tags: iphone, xcode

Whenever I try to build my iPhone app in Xcode 3.2.1 I get an error that says:

> Code Sign error: The identity 'iPhone Distribution: foo' doesn't match any identity in any profile

This is a distribution certificate, however it worked perfectly with a developer certificate.

I have revoked and installed all of my iPhone certificates, and Google hasn't been of much help either. How can I build my app without this error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This looks similar to an [earlier question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1072311/), that says you need to generate a new provisioning profile for your new certificate.

EDIT:

From looking at the Code Sign error, it seems it is trying to match up your distribution certificate with a provisioning profile. 
I have not yet distributed an app to the App Store, but it seems you have to create an "App Store Distribution Provisioning Profile". See [this doc](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/manage/distribution/index.action) from the Apple Developer Connection.

Comment: Thanks for the response, but I need to fix the distribution certificate, not the developer certificate (which works perfectly). In other words, I need to code sign this app to distribute it on the App Store.