# cannot compile my iphone app under xcode

Tags: iphone, xcode

It says code sign error. What should I change maybe in plist to cancel this error ?

The question here [Xcode iPhone project Code Signing error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1549225/xcode-iphone-project-code-signing-error) doesn't answer my problem:

I don't want to run my app on my iphone just on SIMULATOR so I don't need to sign.

In fact I have compiled successfully several times without that message.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1549225/xcode-iphone-project-code-signing-error

Comment: See my update your link doesn't suit my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're getting that error, you're building for the device, not for the simulator. Change the selection in the big top-left target dropdown in Xcode to check "Simulator", not "Device".