# Code Signing error in Xcode

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode4

I've looked through all other topics on this issue, and I can't still solve my problem. I did a clean install of OS X today, and now when I try to run on my iOS device I get an error stating:
Check dependencies

[BEROR]Code Sign error: The identity 'iPhone Developer' doesn't match any valid certificate/private key pair in the default keychain

I don't know how to solve this, I have tried going through my Code Signing identities and saying to 'Don't sign code', but it still isn't working.

I've deleted my phone from my provisioning profile, and then re-added it. I've deleted my certificate and also re-added It still isn't working. I began this Xcode project before I did a clean install and this is the origination of the problem.

Any help is much appreciated,
thanks

Comment: are you testing it in simulator?

Comment: "I have tried going through my Code Signing identities and saying to 'Don't sign code', but it still isn't working." You have to code-sign to test on device as far as I know

Comment: Open keychain Access and see if you can find the required certificate under "My Certificates"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you set the same provisioning profile in your target settings ?

```
You need to create a new provisioning profile with your new CSR.
```

OR

> Go to project settings Search for all "CODE_SIGN_IDENTITY[sdk=iphonesos*]" and set it to "CODE_SIGN_IDENTITY[sdk=iphonesos*]" = "iPhone Developer"; Searach for "PROVISIONING_PROFILE[sdk=iphonesos*]" and set it to "PROVISIONING_PROFILE[sdk=iphonesos*]" = ""; Now Save the file

OR then the main problem with your key chain:

> At last if both of the answer above could not solve the issue then check open your keychain access and check whether you do not have two "iPhone Distribution" certificates in my keychain, **delete one of them if you have any duplicate.**

**Go to your apple provisioning portal and create a new provisioning profile with new csr. and after that clean all the targets and build fresh binary with your provisioning profile. some time quit the xcode solve the issue**

Comment: Deleting every certificate key, then regenerating both a distribution and development provisioning profile, and quitting and relaunching Xcode, solved the problem.

Comment: @SaamJB great, that is why i gave you every step, i do not know but sometimes quitting the xcode fix the issue you never know :)

Answer (score 1):

build setting->code signing identity->debug->your team provisioning profile

select perticular team provisioning and try again

Answer (score 0):

i think this question from stack overflow would help  you...

[Code Sign error: The identity 'iPhone Developer' doesn't match any valid certificate/private key pair in the default keychain](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2108503/code-sign-error-the-identity-iphone-developer-doesnt-match-any-valid-certific)

if you are testing it in simulator just right click on your app name and select Get Info
then select Base SDK info to Latest Ios and then close it,
then click on your app name near active target ,
then select simulator and build it........