# iPhone Developer' doesn't match any valid, non-expired certificate/private key pair-BUT I'm creating and Ipad app

Tags: iphone, xcode, ipad, certificate

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Code Sign error: The identity ‘iPhone Developer’ doesn’t match any valid certificate/private key pair in the default keychain](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2108503/code-sign-error-the-identity-iphone-developer-doesnt-match-any-valid-certifi)

Why do I get this message when I have specified that I am developing for the iPad and not for the iPhone ? Is there a separate private key that I need ? When I look at Keychain Access Certificates I do have a valid iPhone Developer certificate valid through Jan. 18,2013. So what's the problem ?

Comment: You shouldn't need separate private key. Have you made the proper provisioning profiles and all that jazz?

Comment: you have tis show up only if you are running it on the iPad and not when running it on the iPhone?

Comment: **I still could not figure out that how you were getting that error when you are not making build for iPhone**. Yeah of course, if you are making the build for device then you will have to have bundle indentifier with your match provisioning profile.

Comment: If you develop on two macs you'll need to export the certificate with the private key from Keychain access and copy it to the other mac, the certificate alone isn't enough

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You dont need a separate private key.

Make sure the bundle identifier in your build settings matches that of the provision profile, the profile which was signed with the certificate that you have in your keychain.

Comment: @JimThio could you be more specific about "that"?

Comment: I resolved this issue by Command + Alt + shift + k. then when I try to archive it smoothly compiled.

Comment: I found it helped me to remove all the  `./project.xcodeproj/xcuserdata/*.xcuserdatad` folders and recreate my schemes and reassign my developer specific settings so that things are provisioned and certificates match.

Comment: @WarrenP instead of deleting that folder, its safer to go to Organizer-->Projects--> Select Current Project --> Delete Derive Data for that current project. That way, you are cleaning out only the derived data for that particular project.

Comment: "Delete Derived Data" is the same as Cmd+Alt+Shift+K right?

Comment: I dont think so. that is to clear any data in ur build folder. I believe derived data is other stuff that sometimes gets messed up, leading to unpredictable behavior.

Comment: Can you explain the process?

Comment: @bwheeler96 "the process" is referring to one of my comments? or is it wrt the answer? If any of the answers available on SO are not clear enough, be kind enough to ask what exactly is to be clarified/explained. If a question has an accepted answer, and you are still not sure how it works, it means you have a valid question, so go ahead and post a new question, instead of commenting on old posts with vague questions. It'll help not only you, but also others who may have similar questions.

Comment: @bwheeler96 Does this help? http://programmersweb.blogspot.com/2011/05/clearing-xcode-4s-derived-data.html

Comment: Ya, the problem was me being stupid. I had my build mode set to like "iPhone deployment" or something. I set it back to iPhone simulator and it worked fine. I hate IDE's