# Profile doesn't match any valid certificate/private key pair in the default keychain

Tags: xcode, provisioning-profile

Last time I try to run my app in device, it works smoothly without any problem.

But now when I try to run it again, Xcode has following error:

> Profile doesn't match any valid certificate/private key pair in the
>   default keychain

I never change my provisioning profile in Xcode as well as private key and certificate in my Keychain.
Anyone knows why?

Comment: Try this thread http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2108503/code-sign-error-the-identity-iphone-developer-doesnt-match-any-valid-certifi?rq=1