# .ipa file using xcode 4.6.1

Tags: iphone, ios6

I am new to iOS and I am developing my first app for the App store.

I now have to generate my .ipa file using archive options from organizer. I am selecting iOS devices at run tab and used the archive option but it is showing the following error:

> "The identity 'iPhone Distribution' doesn't match any valid, non-expired certificate/private key pair in your key chains"

I am not attaching my device to Xcode. I want to create .ipa file for sending it to one of my friends for testing using his iPhone.

Comment: check your certificates and provisioning profile whether they are expired or they are invalid

Comment: no they are not invalid/expired in keychain they are saiyng it valid

Comment: can you generate the provision profile and ceritificates

Comment: Please don't scream! See whether the bundle identifier in your build settings matches that of the provision profile,

Comment: then properly set your provisioning profile sometimes we make mistake while setting the provisioning profile

Comment: @micro i didnt understand how we can check both names

Comment: see [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2112971/1756131) and [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6367190/1756131)

Comment: it is showing erroe profile doent match in your private keachain accesss ahatit means???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A quick fix: on your Xcode project, look for a folder called "Products", and find your .app file there. You will need to create a folder called "Payload", and put the .app file inside that folder. Once you do this, you can compress the folder, and change the name to yourapp.ipa file. This will be a valid .ipa file signed with the provisioning credentials you used to compile the file.

Keep in mind that the proper way to set up this is to setup a schema for archive, in which you sign the app with the "release" settings, and with a valid ad-hoc distribution profile. But for now, you can use the initial quick fix so you can send your friend the app.

Comment: i didint understand what u r trying to say

Comment: is is showing an error  The identity 'iPhone Distribution' doesn't match any valid, non-expired certificate/private key pair in your keychains

Comment: is it neccessary to add device for generationg .ipa file?

Comment: Are you add .p12 file in to keychain Access?

Comment: drag that file into keychain access 
so please add certificates and .p12 into keychain access properly.

Comment: which files? certificates??