# Can't deploy iOS application to phone

Tags: iphone, xcode, deployment

So I made my first iPhone application, and I wanted to test it on my actual device.  I clicked in Xcode's organizer "Use for Development," and then I accidentally typed the wrong password for my developer's account.  Now whenever I try to test on my phone, I get:

```
Code Sign error: The identity 'iPhone Developer' doesn't match any valid, non-expired certificate/private key pair in your keychains
```

And I can't seem to figure out how to fix that.  I tried doing something with provisioning profiles and it says that my team is too small.

How do I fix this?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

See Apple TN2250: https://developer.apple.com/legacy/library/technotes/tn2250/ on solving most keychain certificate errors.

Answer (score 0):

I did a negative test for you and deleted all of my provisioning profiles on my development iPhone (Settings->General->Profiles, remove one by one). Having on my laptop the proper profiles and my IPhone without any profiles I confirm that I can test and run my app on device by simply run the project on device.

So it is likely that the problem is not because you accidentally made a typo in your password but more likely that your project' building properties are not correct and/or your provisioning profile not matches your app's settings.

You can really find many info how to handle such situations [here at SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2108503/code-sign-error-the-identity-iphone-developer-doesnt-match-any-valid-certifi) or other places [like Apple's developer site.](https://developer.apple.com/support/technical/code-signing/)

Eg. the mentioned SO answer says this error happens if you forgot to change your build settings to Simulator. Try this and also reload your provisioning profiles in Organizer (some cases Xcode should be also restarted).