# Keychain error from imported project

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, keychain

I have imported an objective C project on my computer, and I have the following error :

> Code Sign error: The identity 'iPhone Developer John Doe (XYZ1234)' doesn't match any valid certificate/private key pair in the default keychain

I have checked this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2108503/code-sign-error-the-identity-iphone-developer-doesnt-match-any-valid-certifi), been to the project properties -> BUild -> Architecture -> Base SDK, and changed to iPhone simulator 3.0. Same problem of course. I'm new under iPhone development, this is my first experience, so I don't know xCode yet.

Could someone explain to me what is the error related to ? I suppose the keychain is related to the user's computer. So I should change the project's keychain by mine. But I don't know how to do. And there is nothing under Provisioning profiles in Organizer.

PS : this is the first time I open the project

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/IDEs/Conceptual/AppDistributionGuide/LaunchingYourApponDevices/LaunchingYourApponDevices.html may help you, are you enrolled i developer apple program??

Comment: Yep, since this morning ;)

Comment: I'm not sure to understand. Does it mean I have to register my virtual device on Apple Developer to use it ?

Comment: Hey no, I made a mistake. I just created an account to download Code, I'm not an enrolled developer ! All I want for the moment is to launch my app with the sources. I don't need this account

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i think you accidentally  select iphone device to run project.If you want to run on simulator see screen shot:[image]

may be this is what you are looking for :)

Thanks

Comment: Yes that's it. This was such a beginner problem I tried to solve for so long. Thanks ! No I can resolve the bugs x)