# Code Sign error: The identity 'iPhone Developer' doesn't match any valid

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, ipod-touch

I have two bundle ID's. In which one is expired 2 days back and one more id is in active. Now I have created my new app with active bundle id but I am not able to run my app in my Ipod touch.

I hot the following error.

Code Sign error: The identity 'iPhone Developer' doesn't match any valid, non-expired certificate/private key pair in your keychains

But when i run my app in simulator it is working fine. But when I run in my ipod touch it is not working.

give me some suggestions to resolve my issue.

Comment: By the time you typed the whole question if you have searched in stackoverflow you would have got answer for your question. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2108503/code-sign-error-the-identity-iphone-developer-doesnt-match-any-valid-certifi

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do the following steps:

1. `Delete` the expired provisioning profile from keychain
2. check with bundle identifier. Then Select corresponding provisioning profile from dropdown(Build
       Settings)
3. `Save and quit` xcode and reopen.

Comment: Thank you for suggestion. Where can I found keychain in Xcode ?

Comment: Just do spotlight search `Keychain Access`? It will show expired one.

Comment: Yeah I got it. Can I delete all expired keys?

Comment: I have small dough. My apple developer certificate is expired. But I have active bundle id. So I want to renew my apple developer certificate? Or no need ?

Comment: Are you sure? Your current developer certificate get expired corresponding to your bundle id? If so, you have to renew and try.