# Help determining why XCode "Failed to upload MyApp.app" to my iPad

Tags: xcode, ios, build

An hour ago everything worked great. I was busy hacking away at my code, deploying it to the simulator or my iPad as I liked, and no problems. Then I thought all the bugs were gone, so I created a new Provisioning Profile for the app and added it to the "Release" Project Settings. Suddenly, I cannot launch the app on my iPad anymore, and the only thing that XCode tells me is "Failed to upload MyApp.app"... no elaboration at all.

I'm still using the Developer Profile (which the organizer assures me is installed on my iPad) for the "Debug" Project Settings.

I tried deleting the most recent version from my iPad, deleting the Build/ directory, and then installing but no joy.

Help, please!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd try removing your provisioning profiles, even going through and manually editing your project file such as described: [Code Sign error: The identity 'iPhone Developer: x Xxxxx' doesn't match any identity in any profile](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1072311/code-sign-error-the-identity-iphone-developer-x-xxxxx-doesnt-match-any-ident)

Then reinstall the profiles.  Anytime I've had an issue like you're describing that has solved the problem for me.

Comment: Thanks! Deleting the profiles and reinstalling them did the trick.