# mac app store -- testing code signing

Tags: macos, app-store, code-signing

I have an app for the Mac app store.  It was rejected due to code signing (I think.  I also have receipt signing, but I don't think that is what Apple is referring to below.)  Here is what Apple had to say:

*The application fails to launch. No crash logs were generated. Console reports that the app is unsigned. This may be due to an improperly signed app or incorrect permissions. Please ensure your app can launch and run under a non-admin user account.*

When I look at the distribution build in XCode, I see this:
CODE_SIGN_IDENTITY = 3rd Party Mac Developer Application: William Jockusch.
The other code signing fields are empty.

When I double click on the built and archived app, it asks me to log in to the app store.  I have no idea what that is all about.

What am I missing?

Comment: One thing to try would be running it from a newly created non-admin account and see if it still launches.

Comment: Is it possible its your profile? [Check this similar question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1072311/code-sign-error-the-identity-iphone-developer-x-xxxxx-doesnt-match-any-ident)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is now fixed.  The login part is related to the receipt signing.  If anyone else runs in to that, you need a sandbox account to test that your receipt signing works.

In addition, there was a problem with the code signing.  The non-admin trick revealed that.

Comment: Can you elaborate on what you did with a non-admin account to determine and fix the problem?

Comment: See cobbal's  comment to my original question.  I don't remember any more than that.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem where Apple said "Console reports that the app is unsigned.", even though I had signed it. The problem was with file permissions. Some files were not readable by everybody, and when the application is not installed on an admin account, the code signature verification will fail.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes it's none of the above and instead something in your Entitlements file. If you're using iCloud, CloudKit or MapKit - the app will *not* launch and report a vague error such as `Terminated due to code signing error`

Simply create a copy of your Entitlements and use a different one when distributing it outside of the App Store - in it, simply remove any reference to iCloud, iCloud Drive, iCloud key value, CloudKit or Maps.