# provisioning profile does not appear in project.pbxproj

Tags: provisioning-profile

I downloaded the sample code of LocateMe program from the developer site of Apple             ( http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/LocateMe/Introduction/Intro.html ). After configuring properties, I tried to build and got the code sign error.

The answer accessed through the following link have been solving this problem for another source codes I downloaded since now. [Code Sign error: The identity 'iPhone Developer: x Xxxxx' doesn't match any identity in any profile](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1072311/code-sign-error-the-identity-iphone-developer-x-xxxxx-doesnt-match-any-ident/3097199#3097199)

This time I couldn't find "PROVISIONING_PROFILE" to change its value.

I would appreciate any help very much.