# ipod application release

Tags: iphone, xcode, release

I just finished writing my first ipod application.  I have been using xcode and simulator and I am very happy with the outcome.  I am now ready to release it to my ipod.  I connected the ipod and changed the target location to device. I clicked on run on xcode and I got an error:

Code Sign error: The identity 'iPhone Developer' doesn't match any valid certificate/private key pair in the default keychain

What does this mean?  I thought I didn't have to join anything if I am not releasing it to the market. I thought I could just do this free.

Thanks
Saro

Comment: possible duplicate of [Code Sign error: The identity 'iPhone Developer: x Xxxxx' doesn't match any identity in any profile](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1072311/code-sign-error-the-identity-iphone-developer-x-xxxxx-doesnt-match-any-ident)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In order to install your app on a device you must be enrolled in the [iOS Developer Program](https://developer.apple.com/programs/ios/).

Answer (score 3):

You have to be a registered Apple Developer ($99 last time I checked) to be able to upload your created apps to your iPhone/iPod/iPad.

See [this page](https://developer.apple.com/programs/ios/) for enrollment to the program.

Answer (score 0):

You must be a registered developer to test applications on physical devices:

You can register [here](https://developer.apple.com/programs/ios/) for $99 per year.

This will also give you access to IOS 5 sdk.